Reconciliation of different results regarding Laplace transform of $\ln(1+t)$
I want to calculate the Laplace transform of $\ln(1+t)u(t)$. We know from
Laplace transform of natural logarithm
that $\mathcal{L}\{\ln t \;u(t)\} = -\frac{\gamma+\ln s}{s}$ where $\gamma$ is the
Euler-Mascheroni constant
and from there using time shift property of Laplace transform we have $\mathcal{L}\{\ln\left(1+t\right)u(t)\} = -e^s\left(\frac{\gamma+\ln s}{s}\right)$.
On the other hand by direct calculations we have
$$\mathcal{L}\{\ln\left(1+t\right)u(t)\} = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}\ln(1+t)dt = -\frac{e^{-st}\ln(1+t)}{s}\Bigg|_{t=0}^{t \to \infty} + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-st}}{s(t+1)}dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-st}}{s(t+1)}dt$$
where  we have used by parts using $f = \ln(1+t), g' = e^{-st}$ and assumed $\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{e^{-st}\ln(1+t)}{s}=0 $ when $\Re\{s\}>0$. Now in the last integral we substitute $u = s(t+1) \rightarrow du = s dt$ and we get
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-st}}{s(t+1)}dt = \frac{e^s}{s}\int_{s}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-u}}{u}du = \frac{e^s}{s}\text{Ei}(-s)$$
where we know that $\text{Ei}(x) = \int_{-x}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-u}}{u}du$ is the
Exponential Integral.
Which one of these are correct? What is my mistake?
Thank you in advance for time and attention!

Accepting that
$$
\mathcal{L}\{\ln t u(t)\}(s) = - \frac{\gamma + \ln s}{s}
$$
and that the time-shift property is given by
$$
\mathcal{L}\{f(t-a)\}(s) = e^{-as} \mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}(s)
$$
then a shift of $a=-1$ should give us
$$
\mathcal{L}(\ln(t+1) u(t+1)\}(s) = -e^s  \frac{\gamma + \ln s}{s}
$$
I think this is where the problem lies: you only shifted the logarithm, not the Heaviside function.

Thanks for this answer! That's actually a good point. Does that mean the first answer is wrong and the second one is correct? I need to use this result in my BSc thesis, I have to make sure it is correct. Thank you!
